# Send a file from HTML/Javascript to Ruby to API

Tags: javascript, ruby, file-upload, sinatra, filereader

I'm writing an app that uploads multiple posts to Tumblr. I'm using Ruby with Sinatra, and since I'm new to both I was wondering how to actually use the files uploaded using the HTML5 multiple file reader.

Here is my Ruby pseudocode in app.rb:

```
post '/' do |file|
    if file is text file
        @@client.text("#{session[:user_id]}.tumblr.com", {:body => "Stuff from index.erb"})
    elsif file is photo file
        @@client.photo("#{session[:user_id]}.tumblr.com", {:data => ['/path/to/pic.jpg']})
    else
        "Sorry, text and photo only at this time."
    end
end
```

And here's my HTML/Javascript in index.erb:

```
<body>
    <h1>File Uploader</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"> 
        <output id="list"></output>
        <div id="progress_bar"><div class="percent">0%</div></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Post Something!">
    </form>

<!-- FILE LOADER -->
<script> 
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>

<!-- PROGRESS BAR -->
<script>
  var reader;
  var progress = document.querySelector('.percent');

  function abortRead() {
    reader.abort();
  }

  function errorHandler(evt) {
    switch(evt.target.error.code) {
      case evt.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
        alert('File Not Found!');
        break;
      case evt.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
        alert('File is not readable');
        break;
      case evt.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
        break; // noop
      default:
        alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
    };
  }

  function updateProgress(evt) {
    // evt is an ProgressEvent.
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
      // Increase the progress bar length.
      if (percentLoaded < 100) {
        progress.style.width = percentLoaded + '%';
        progress.textContent = percentLoaded + '%';
      }
    }
  }

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    // Reset progress indicator on new file selection.
    progress.style.width = '0%';
    progress.textContent = '0%';

    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
    reader.onprogress = updateProgress;
    reader.onabort = function(e) {
      alert('File read cancelled');
    };
    reader.onloadstart = function(e) {
      document.getElementById('progress_bar').className = 'loading';
    };
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      // Ensure that the progress bar displays 100% at the end.
      progress.style.width = '100%';
      progress.textContent = '100%';
      setTimeout("document.getElementById('progress_bar').className='';", 2000);
    }

    // Read in the image file as a binary string.
    reader.readAsBinaryString(evt.target.files[0]);
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</body>
```

Once I have the actual file objects, I can send them to Tumblr via the Ruby code, BUT I don't really know how to get the file from index.erb to the Ruby code. Should I put the Ruby code inside the .erb file?

TL;DR:

1.) How can I convert whatever the Javascript returns into a readable file for Ruby? I want to return the photos as files, and the text as parseable text.

2.) How can I send the file returned by Javascript to Ruby to send to Tumblr?

Comment: Have you read about how to handle just one file with Sinatra? It might give you a good starting point. http://www.wooptoot.com/file-upload-with-sinatra